# JQuery : Submit event not firing on FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't understand why the submit event described below is not firing on FireFox and IE.
Ok for Chrome

> ```
> $("#frame-right").on("submit", "form", function(event){                  
>     alert('Submit done')
> });
> ```

Can you help me?

**EDIT**

The forms are submitting by pressing a "submit" button, but the forms are included in page loaded through .load() function and not exist when the function above is defined.

FYI, at the same place, I defined this function which is working fine on all browser

```
$("#frame-right").on("click","a",function(event){
alert('link clicked');
}
```

Is the "submit" event can be bound dynamically like "click" event?

**EDIT 2**

Thanks for your reply.
The problem is that after a load() function, the form loaded cannot be submitted with Firefox

Comment: What's the HTML for the page? Do you get any Javascript errors?

Comment: No JS error, just nothing append. The code is not called; checked with FireBug

Comment: how are you submitting the form? clicking on a button or programmatically triggering the submit? what happens if you do $("#frame-right").trigger('submit');

Comment: The forms are submitting by pressing a "submit" button, but the forms are included in page loaded through .load() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake...

After long tests, I have discovered that a form must be declared inside a table element  ou outside the table...

This exemple doesn't work :

```
<table>
  <form>
    <tr><td><button type="submit">Submit</button></td></tr>
  </form>
</table>
```

This exemple works :

```
<form>
  <table>    
    <tr><td><button type="submit">Submit</button></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: This turns out to be the exact problem I was having and this fixed it. Any idea why this is the case though? I want to have multiple forms within table rows...

Comment: You can declare a form inside a `<td>` : `<table><tr><td><form></form></td></tr></table>`

Comment: But like you my forms are included in a <td> by being loaded with Ajax at which point my on("submit" event handler is not attaching..?

Answer (score 0):

so you should attach that listener in the callback for your load function to make sure it gets attached after the forms have been loaded in.

so for example:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {


    $("#frame-right").on("submit", "form", function(event){                  
        alert('Submit done')
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Make sure you are preventing the default submit behaviour when doing  the ajax stuff.

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on("submit", "form", function(event){   
      event.preventDefault() ;  // prevent dfaul submit behaviour
      alert("submitting")
  });
});
```